# receiving or delete image on the gallery affect or crash my app

Tags: android, android-intent, lifecycle

I just finish my app and i'm doing test and I found this bug when I do this behavior or this action . sorry for my language i'm not native English

so :  i'm using intent.action_pick  to select images and work prefect fine but the problem start  while the intent is running  waiting me for selection I do make the app Onpause Status means I do leave the app to open the gallery or on case the gallery just  got update for example receive new image from whatsap or I delete some image  on the gallery while my app Onpause Status  so once I get back to my app  the app just start from the begging . the action that i did make the app restart i don't think so I can't say crash or stop  it's about something on life cycle  !

so how can I keep my app on the same status before I leave it or how to prevent my app from restart ! however that same thing  accrue   when changing screen orientation!   Please I need help I really appreciate your time

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK  , android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);//
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        startActivityForResult(intent, slect_photo);
```

Comment: can u check the logcat, what does it says

Comment: Use onSaveInstanceState() to save your state.

Comment: Is there any crash log?

Answer (score 0):

thank you guys  @ Ticherhaz FreePalestine, @ blackapps, @ Anna

I found out that my phone stop my app after I leave it for while on the background my phone do this for saving power battery  . so when I go to setting I allowed my app to be running on the background. so that setting kept my app run on the same status before I leave it . right now i'm thinking to do service intent on order to give user options allow him to leave the app run on the background